# CrossEntropyLoss: Target -1 is out of bounds

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

**!!! I got a solution for this issue. I'll post it later.**

I'm creating an audio classifier which categorizes a song into 50 latent factors.
A song consists of a 128x10377 matrix which is convoluted by a 1d conv layer.
When training the model I get the error `Target -1 is out of bounds.` after different times.

Custom Dataset Class:

```
# Sound Dataset
# ----------------------------
class SoundDS(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, df, data_path):
    self.df = df
    self.data_path = str(data_path)
    self.duration = 10377 # (columns in spectrogram)
            
  # ----------------------------
  # Number of items in dataset
  # ----------------------------
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.df)    
    
  # ----------------------------
  # Get i'th item in dataset
  # ----------------------------
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    # Absolute file path of the audio file - concatenate the audio directory with
    # the relative path
    audio_file = self.df.iloc[idx, 0]
    # Get the 50 latent factors
    latent_factors = np.array(self.df.iloc[idx, 2:52], dtype=np.float64) 
    latent_factors = torch.from_numpy(latent_factors)
    latent_factors = latent_factors.type(torch.LongTensor)

    aud = AudioUtil.open(audio_file)
    # Some sounds have a higher sample rate, or fewer channels compared to the
    # majority. So make all sounds have the same number of channels and same 
    # sample rate. Unless the sample rate is the same, the pad_trunc will still
    # result in arrays of different lengths, even though the sound duration is the same.

    sgram = AudioUtil.spectro_gram(aud, n_mels=128, n_fft=1024, hop_len=512)
    sgram_resized, sr = AudioUtil.pad_trunc(sgram, self.duration)
    sgram_resized = torch.from_numpy(sgram_resized)

    return sgram_resized, latent_factors
```

Model:

```
class AudioClassifier (nn.Module):
    # ----------------------------
    # Build the model architecture
    # ----------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        conv_layers = []

        # First Convolution Block with Relu and Batch Norm. Use Kaiming Initialization
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=6)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        init.kaiming_normal_(self.conv1.weight, a=0.1)
        self.conv1.bias.data.zero_()

        conv_layer1 = [self.conv1, self.relu1]
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(*conv_layer1)

        # Second Layer: 1. Max Pooling Layer
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=4)
        
        # Third Layer: 2. Convolution Block
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=128, kernel_size=6)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        init.kaiming_normal_(self.conv2.weight, a=0.1)
        self.conv2.bias.data.zero_()

        conv_layer2 = [self.conv2, self.relu2]
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(*conv_layer2)

        # Fourth layer: 2. Max Pooling layer
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=5)

        # Hidden full connected layer
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(517, 400)

        # Output layer
        # With 50 outputs for 50 latent factors
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(400, 50)
 
    # ----------------------------
    # Forward pass computations
    # ----------------------------
    def forward(self, x):

        # Run the convolutional blocks
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        # Final output
        return x
```

Training:

```
def training(model, train_dl, num_epochs):
  # Loss Function, Optimizer and Scheduler
  criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.001)
  scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.OneCycleLR(optimizer, max_lr=0.001,
                                                steps_per_epoch=int(len(train_dl)),
                                                epochs=num_epochs,
                                                anneal_strategy='linear')

  # Repeat for each epoch
  for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0
    correct_prediction = 0
    total_prediction = 0

    # Repeat for each batch in the training set
    for i, data in enumerate(train_dl):
        # Get the input features and target labels, and put them on the GPU
        inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)

        # Normalize the inputs
        inputs_m, inputs_s = inputs.mean(), inputs.std()
        inputs = (inputs - inputs_m) / inputs_s

        # Zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels) # Here the error occurs
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

        # Keep stats for Loss and Accuracy
        running_loss += loss.item()

        # Get the predicted class with the highest score
        _, prediction = torch.max(outputs,1)
        # Count of predictions that matched the target label
        correct_prediction += (prediction == labels).sum().item()
        total_prediction += prediction.shape[0]
    
    # Print stats at the end of the epoch
    num_batches = len(train_dl)
    avg_loss = running_loss / num_batches
    acc = correct_prediction/total_prediction
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, Loss: {avg_loss:.2f}, Accuracy: {acc:.2f}')

  print('Finished Training')
```

`data[0]` is the name of the track and `data[1]` are the 50 latent factors:

One batch of labeled training data would look like this:

```
,Track_Id,Song_Id,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
0,TRATLOJ128F9308ABB,SOAAAQN12AB01856D3,-0.040126301,-0.168908251,0.031135923,-0.064337786,-0.00552958,-0.00654607,-0.137657523,0.023066403,-0.026992316,0.091566442,0.111935577,0.035118404,-0.009976452,0.106386754,0.066842984,0.016382154,-0.030213757,0.076204832,-0.01693836,-0.030881624,0.003248707,-0.08918263,0.076869535,-0.11021608,-0.044136737,-0.097478285,0.017421233,-0.012732468,0.14160713,0.109010054,0.000906,-0.00621637,0.017150649,-0.028789245,0.111733808,0.020244641,0.016060879,-0.021917386,0.012973345,0.083301077,0.138817772,-0.020363399,0.000992899,0.044581326,-0.021401301,-0.069762513,-0.114974153,-0.075231937,-0.026619645,-0.027308014
1,TRAYPFH128E07937C3,SOAAEHR12A6D4FB060,-0.288891429,-0.069881434,-0.171068474,0.115362731,0.054818042,0.038151977,0.088589221,-0.091052396,0.10252821,-0.089296442,-0.09597865,0.210080966,0.053387155,0.264014569,0.110896803,-0.143541245,-0.049237182,-0.056330723,-0.380358298,0.239908636,-0.184735881,0.168522284,-0.022791649,0.143439856,-0.252363486,0.264970016,0.096833886,-0.242972065,-0.179452972,0.03640556,0.040300881,0.035472799,0.00373689,0.509958531,0.31777464,0.281520557,-0.135021204,-0.02192096,0.077038831,0.155089767,0.338304221,-0.430334993,-0.378225446,-0.236491543,-0.229114664,-0.182495994,0.199933443,0.011379453,-0.045047692,-0.032486882
2,TRAMPCN12903CC4E5B,SOAAFUV12AB018831D,0.000698322,-0.021696691,0.008980767,-0.010957474,0.002339249,0.005746675,0.00015513,0.000306602,0.00282736,0.005172744,0.002766998,-0.01308903,-0.012614581,-0.003409039,-0.009787931,-0.009457383,0.006352099,0.016028015,0.00177784,0.007189919,0.005254775,0.014133498,0.011658114,-0.002501851,-0.006498972,0.010875,0.009569642,-0.016649991,-0.007850105,0.007172746,0.001264481,0.002247948,-0.01229619,0.006101766,-0.005344646,0.011287564,-0.000449569,0.003996594,0.000825234,0.006348792,0.013771403,0.002225991,0.005057246,-0.005771025,-0.007094359,-0.00952727,0.005919218,0.008195133,-0.008774238,0.00086909
3,TRBDLDS128F429C171,SOAANKE12A8C13CF5C,2e-05,-8.83e-06,-1.32e-06,-1.27e-05,1.23e-05,-7.96e-06,-8.55e-06,7.34e-07,-9.49e-06,1.37e-05,-1.27e-05,-1.7e-05,4.76e-07,1.89e-05,2.17e-05,-2.06e-05,-8.17e-06,-5.73e-06,6.45e-06,3.74e-06,-4.57e-06,2.37e-06,9.78e-06,-8.56e-06,6.75e-07,-5.72e-06,-7.24e-07,1.22e-05,3.66e-06,9.07e-06,4.83e-06,-7.82e-06,-1.06e-05,-1.43e-05,5.22e-06,-1.5e-05,-4.07e-06,1.08e-05,1.59e-05,-1.6e-05,1.49e-05,9.43e-07,-1.36e-05,-4.32e-06,1.22e-05,9e-06,-1.49e-06,2.92e-06,-5.73e-06,1.39e-06
4,TRAQHPK128F92E339B,SOAASSD12AB0181AA6,-0.033159141,-0.020840837,-0.020173998,0.005378895,-0.060872699,-0.038994122,-0.019800342,0.071491855,0.009998184,-0.005483134,0.039544332,-0.015522613,-0.027479666,0.004782119,-0.06847504,0.07176027,0.009815599,0.001405589,-0.009707233,-0.011128278,-0.002572611,-0.001154622,0.050143771,0.025207446,-0.026022977,0.056758869,-0.042455558,-0.015029411,-0.045271783,-0.024126178,-0.018142288,0.009665729,0.040873529,0.018746185,0.009433124,0.009748801,0.049024627,0.018638494,0.001333625,-0.025114106,-0.019449129,-0.029315642,-0.043723715,-0.050268717,0.017085383,0.020465196,-0.010714675,-0.006128655,0.07555133,0.011330641
5,TRATHPX128F9341B8A,SOABFQI12A58A7D162,0.022860767,0.026635475,0.036878428,0.015748217,-0.042116391,-0.041154747,0.040483549,-0.049399729,-0.054099598,-0.039425176,0.035130855,0.0122507,0.03907898,0.009049182,-0.037191976,0.005028183,0.02332725,0.085420539,-0.052562967,-0.041384202,-0.002896427,0.000874385,0.021324215,-0.03646968,-0.030479014,-0.006800864,0.015441012,0.066623111,0.058655576,0.036857939,0.038614326,0.050882084,0.020634715,-0.011000549,-0.030993432,-0.014145144,-0.003877321,-0.022080026,-0.020329419,0.048505293,0.064057942,0.039775231,0.027236732,0.043234455,-0.014915377,-0.022404278,-0.064497836,-0.085231886,0.002868261,0.007765321
6,TRABUMO12903CBE25F,SOABLAF12AB018E1D9,0.112678477,-0.061965526,0.03285993,-0.212098867,0.061974154,0.140864329,0.068215841,0.10511197,-0.092935413,-0.304596401,0.0559515,0.13451356,0.497678347,0.391745623,0.206301064,-0.163743207,0.022598818,0.063998501,-0.180294246,-0.189100209,0.346031753,0.041273179,0.488278692,0.405221746,-0.102114227,-0.125511602,-0.071605966,0.601972982,-0.042147064,-0.125230052,0.126606035,0.132842748,-0.057230431,0.21035045,-0.374677176,-0.105962501,-0.185452124,-0.069090839,-0.247809692,0.307558132,-0.177418498,0.048898636,-0.092760284,-0.008935301,-0.234226897,-0.39224315,0.240701108,-0.243334333,0.090855942,-0.112232065
7,TRBCWPC128F42438DF,SOABRXK12A8C130A36,-0.207344335,-0.123072121,0.023283585,0.137457333,0.159253907,0.160407638,0.059840592,0.092897478,0.013930228,0.153691653,0.048670884,-0.047410477,0.364060607,-0.06589021,0.177215679,0.032860579,0.013377746,-0.011780143,-0.111212536,0.023483095,0.209117323,-0.011067618,-0.066623111,0.243345187,-0.197707376,0.128615479,0.191302158,0.08420858,-0.066465533,-0.14839338,-0.059592938,0.038454081,-0.051401377,-0.08637496,-0.193148787,0.063237328,-0.075434721,0.059754377,0.084927961,-0.184603009,-0.042980067,-0.028158878,0.116105517,0.044920261,-0.033457269,-0.049887743,-0.069848559,-0.050518583,-0.117937799,0.000221837
```

Each batch contains 8 spectrograms with a shape of 128 x 10377

```
for batch in train_dl:
    print(batch[0].shape)
    print(batch[1])
    print(batch[1].shape)
    break
```

```
torch.Size([8, 128, 10377])
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0]])
torch.Size([8, 50])
```

Error message:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

---> 15 training(myModel, train_dl, num_epochs)

Cell In[5], line 33, in training(model, train_dl, num_epochs)
     31 # forward + backward + optimize
     32 outputs = model(inputs)
---> 33 loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     34 loss.backward()
     35 optimizer.step()

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:1174, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
   1173 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1174     return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1175                            ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1176                            label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:3029, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3027 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3028     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3029 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)

IndexError: Target -1 is out of bounds.
```

What is wrong can anyone guide me! Thank you!

Comment: Can you share sample data and a script that trains your model and shows the error, so I could replicate it?

Comment: @YakovDan I added the formatting of a batch. I hope this helps. I'm not able to share the 128x10377 matrices.